# Serverless Invalid variable reference syntax for variable ([\s\S]+?)

Tags: serverless-framework

I am getting the following error when doing a serverless deploy

```
Invalid variable reference syntax for variable ([\s\S]+?). You can only reference env vars, options, & files. You can check our docs for more info.
```

I think it is caused by the following line in my serverless.yml (in the environment block of the provider block):

```
variableSyntax: "\\${{([\\s\\S]+?)}}"
```

Why is this invalid? Or is the error actually elsewhere, and if it is, how can I see what line in what file is causing the error?

Comment: Could you post the serverless.yml?

Comment: What's your reason for changing the `variableSyntax`?

Comment: @NoelLlevares it's inherited code but comments say it's because { and } are used in CloudFormation elsewhere in the file. I would be happy to leave the variable syntax as is but I also don't want to break anything.